# C# WPF Notification Popup usercontrol as DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, popup

I'm building a notification popup to use in my projects. (C# WPF .NET).

I have built a usercontrol and I want to display it in the right top corner, pretty much like [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io), but for my c# projects.
[image]

But I can't do it because I don't know how to display it without having a contentControl or something like that to hold it's content.

This is my notification usercontrol to be displayed:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#A5DC86" Margin="10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="CheckCircleOutline" Foreground="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" x:Name="messageText" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource MaterialDesignPaper}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I displayed it to test with this in my window xaml

`<local:NotificationControl x:Name="notificationControl" Visibility="Collapsed"/>`

How can I do it without xaml? Because it's supposed to be a DLL something like `Notification.ShowPopup("my notif");`
Also using the z-index to put it above the other contents

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: You should create a custom control that extends `ToolTip` for a simple notification bubble. If you want to show a list of notifications then extend `Popup` and use a single DispatcherTimer to control the display time of all notifications. UserControl is the wrong choice here.

Comment: @BionicCode Extending as a tooltip, can I position it in the top right corner? I've thought of extending it as a Popup, but that means that if I minimize the window, the popup will remain in the middle of the screen, right? That's why I want something like sweetalert2 on browser

Comment: A ToolTip is more lightweight than a Popup. It's a ContentControl that has a similar API and behavior but has a show duration feature that is configurable using the ToolTipService. This means you position it like a Popup using the Placement, PlacementTargert, VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset. Because the ToolTip is a ContentControl it is easily customizable (without extra efforts) by the client of your library.

Comment: Because it is a ContentControl it will be a child of the visual tree (opposed to the Popup, which is actually showing a complete Window that is naturally detached from the current visual tree). And because it is a child of the visual tree, it will become hidden once the root Window is minimized.

Comment: When you register your ToolTip control with the ToolTipService by assigning the instance to the ToolTipService.ToolTip attached property you can control e.g. show duration using the ToolTipService.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it without xaml?

Create an instance of your control programmatically and then add it to the window one way or another. I guess you want to add it as a child of the root panel of the window (`this` refers to the window in the example below):

```
NotificationControl ctrl = new NotificationControl();
Panel root = this.Content as Panel;
if (root != null)
    root.Children.Add(ctrl);
else
    this.Content = ctrl;
```

Comment: @RafaelBento: Did you try this?